Fix for "Failed to generate cache key for URL"?
I'm using the alchemy-sdk with Next.js 14, and I get a warning message "Failed to generate cache key for https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/[api-key]". The api key is a simple alchemy api key in an environment variable. How does Next.js handle caching of api keys? I cannot find anything related to this warning or how to solve it ... Please share anything useful!

This is the code that generates the cache key in nextjs. You might want to go to your node_modules, find that code, and put some debug in there like console log the error or something like that

That's a great idea, and I've found this code in the next node_module, but it's not really clear to me how to debug it. Any changes there do not reflect in the app. Is there any way of verifying which code from node_modules is actually run?

Just put a console log in it and check if it shows on your terminal. Remember to delete the .next folder and restart your dev server because your modules might be cached

This seems to be caused by a cache for hot reloads in local development.
From Next 15 onwards, you can disable this cache like this in next.config.js:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    serverComponentsHmrCache: false, // defaults to true
  },
}
 
module.exports = nextConfig

See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/config/next-config-js/serverComponentsHmrCache for more info.
